# How to fix this kind of error when trying to run artisan serve in laravel framework 8.0?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, php-8

[image]

I have an error below when i try to run the artisan serve in laravel framework. I dont know what is the root cause of the error. It was working before then when i close the connection and rerun it again. i got an error fclose(): Argument #1 ($stream) must be of type resource, bool given

Comment: I could be wrong but I think this is a permissions issue with the `storage/framework/cache` directory. You can test this by recursively changing the permission of the directory to 777.

Comment: try `composer install`

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the full text of the error, as text not an image, so that more people will be able to read it, and other people with the same error can find your question (and its answer) in future. Please also include the code that gives that error - ideally a [mcve] rather than your real application code.

Answer (score 0):

If you delete the `vendor` folder of your laravel project and if you download it again with comand `composer install` but you get an error then what you have to do is download composer again from the official website and try the initial procedure.
[Web composer](https://getcomposer.org/)